# Download CSV file from SQL result in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I want to get the result of a `SQL` query in `CSV` format. I am using `PHP` for this. My code works fine for the results but I am unable to get to the **column names as header**. Please help

```
@ $con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
if($con->connect_error)
    die("Unable to connect to database : ".$con->connect_error);

$query = "SELECT * FROM User";
$result = $con->query($query);
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    die;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
          if ( !empty( $_POST["tableName"]) ):
            if ( $columData = $db->cPanelAccess("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$_POST["tableName"])):
              ?>
              <tr class="header row">
              <?php
                while ($columName = $columData->fetch_assoc()):
                ?>
                  <td class="fieldNames"><?php echo $columName["Field"]; ?></td>
                <?php
                endwhile;
                ?>
                </tr>
              <?php
            endif;
          endif;
```

I use something like that to print the table headers

Comment: @Mark That's a direct snippet from my site that's why. I assumed OP knows to extract the useful parts for him

Comment: I want to download CSV file. Just it. My code works fine, but I am not getting the column names of the SQL table as the header.